# Like Box Vs. Like Button - When logged in, counting doesn't match

Tags: facebook

I came here looking forward to find people with the same problem as mine but didn't found.

So, I'm trying to discover why on a website, when logged into facebook and you just like that page, the count between Like Box and Like Button plugins doesn't match. Here's a screenshot detailing it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdTnP.jpg

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: #firstworldproblem ? Seriously; I guess the one box does not count yourself while the other does? Or a time delay issue ...?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't retroactively increase the count on one plugin when you click Like on the other - if for some reason this is really important for your app, you could listen for the `edge.create` callback in Javascript and manually refresh the plugins on the page,

When they reload they should both have the same count ( allowing for cache timeouts on Facebook's side, etc)